# How to modify markup in Refinery CMS menu partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, refinerycms

I have done the rake override for _header, _menu, and _menu_branch.html.erb files.  What I would like to do is modify the markup of the menus so that an icon is shown next to the title.

I think the file I want is menu.html.erb, below:

```
  <ul>
    <%= render :partial => '/refinery/menu_branch', :collection => roots,
           :locals => {
             :hide_children => hide_children,
             :sibling_count => (roots.length - 1),
             :menu_levels => local_assigns[:menu_levels],
             :apply_css => true #if you don't care about class='first' class='last' or class='selected' set apply_css to false for speed.
   } -%>
 </ul>
```

What I don't get is that there seems to be nowhere to add a span element or anchor tag that would allow me to specify an icon.  Where might I find that code?  I am aware that my question probably betrays a fundamental lack of understanding in the way Refinery structures it's pages - any resources you could point me to beyond the intro docs would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
render :partial => '/refinery/menu_branch',
```

calls another partial wherein the list items are specified

Comment: Can you tell me how the rake command has got to look like in order to get that?

Comment: i believe it would be rake refinery:override view=refinery/menu

Comment: What version do you use? It seems in the newest (2.1.0) there is no `_menu.html.erb` anymore...

Comment: I was referring to 2.0